# getting import error following scrapy tutorial

Tags: python, django, import, scrapy

Following a scrapy tutorial I am getting an import error.

my structure is

```
stalk
|-bin
|-include
|-lib
|-properties
    |-properties
    |   |-spiders\
    |   |-__init__.py
    |   |-items.py
    |   |-pipelines.py
    |   |-settings.py
    |
    |scrapy.cfg
```

my items.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class PropertiesItem(Item):
    # Primary fields
    title = Field()
    price = Field()
    description = Field()
    address = Field()
    image_urls = Field()
    # Calculated fields
    images = Field()
    location = Field()
    # Housekeeping fields
    url = Field()
    project = Field()
    spider = Field()
    server = Field()
    date = Field()
    pass
```

my basic.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from properties.items import PropertiesItem


class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "basic"
    allowed_domains = ["web"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.example.com/',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        result = response.xpath('//*[@id="cap"]/a/h5/text()').extract()
        # self.log("title :{}".format(result))
        item = PropertiesItem()
        item['title'] = result
        pass
```

when I try to import this

```
from properties.items import PropertiesItem
```

the word items is highlited and PropertiesItem  has red squiggly error lines under it. What am I doing wrong?

Edit Im using django 1.10 and python 3.5

Comment: Did you see the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE ?

Comment: Your tree is a bit weird. Could you post output of `tree` if you're running unix? There definitely seems to be a problem with your structure if python can't detect `properties` module. Do you by any chance have `__init__.py` in root `properties` directory? This is the [tree you should be expecting](http://pastebin.com/raw/Pqv2dNZJ)